# Filtro em DropDown utilizando C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho um dropdown na minha view que preencho da seguinte maneira:

```
 ViewBag.NfeStatus = EnumHelper
      .ListAll<NfeStatus>()
      .ToSelectList(x => x, x => x.Description());
```

Meu model NfeStatus é um enum:

```
public enum NfeStatus
{
    [Description("-")]
    NotIssued = 0,
    [Description("Pendente")]
    Pending,
    [Description("Erro")]
    Error,
    [Description("Ok")]
    Ok
}
```

Porém gostaria de não exibir a opção "OK".

Como realizo este friltro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adicione um filtro usando [`.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx).

Algo como **`.Where(x => x != NfeStatus.Ok)`**.

Ou **`.Where(x => x.Description() != "OK")`** se você preferir buscar pela descrição, embora eu ache que não exista motivo pra isso.

Exemplo

```
ViewBag.NfeStatus = EnumHelper.ListAll<NfeStatus>()
                              .Where(x => x != NfeStatus.Ok)
                              .ToSelectList(x => x, x => x.Description());
```

Ou, usando a descrição:

```
ViewBag.NfeStatus = EnumHelper.ListAll<NfeStatus>()
                              .Where(x => x.Description() != "OK")
                              .ToSelectList(x => x, x => x.Description());
```